# Natural structure over a set of measurable functions

Tags: functional-analysis, probability-theory

Let $(\Omega, \mathcal{F}, \mathbb{P})$ be a probability space. Let $U$ be the set of all measurable functions over $(\Omega, \mathcal{F}, \mathbb{P})$ - i.e. the elements of $U$ are all measurable functions $\zeta : \Omega \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$. Is there a natural algebraic/topological structure on $U$? Is there a full-developed theory regarding the generalities of such sets? I am familiar with advanced geometry/topology and (commutative) algebra, but not with probability theory or functional analysis. References are also welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest that the $L^p$-metrics and their associated topologies are the best attempts to put topological structure onto the measurable functions, though they are all defined on only a subset of your $U$. Basically, we define the $L^p$-norm, $|| \cdot ||_p$, such that $$||f||_p = \left(\int_\Omega |f|^p d\mathbb{P}\right)^{1/p}.$$ The subset of $U$ with finite $L^p$-norm we call $L^P(\Omega, \mathcal{F}, \mathbb{P})$, and we give it the metric topology $d(f, g) = ||f-g||_p.$

This is all the very elementary functional analysis, and I'd suggest you find yourself an elementary text dealing with that and Lebesgue probability spaces. Hopefully someone will stop by with a good learning reference.